# How to use our own I/O framework inside a Thrift client?

Tags: c++, thrift

On the server side, everything is ok.

But on the client side, it seems we cannot just use Thrift to process the protocol, and send/receive the data by using our own I/O framework(such as muduo or other ones).

Is there any way to implement this with C++?

Comment: show us some code, what have you tried, what is not working. Providing own `TTransport` implementation should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks for comments. 

Yes, implement another TTransport maybe work, but is that means I need to rebuild thrift src? or just implement my lib outside, and compile with thrift?  I'm NOT sure the thrift automatic generated code is still ok when I implement this outside from thrift. 

By all means, I don't want to change or add code in thrift src for compatibility reason. 

If you know some open src which implement their TTransport without invade into thrift src, just use the interface and base class, please give me the link or any other hints, appreciate for that!

Comment: you can implement own TTransport without touching thrift src - just extend base class and provide it to client (instead of TSocket for example).
I'm pretty sure contrib directory inside thrift source (https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=tree;f=contrib;h=86143d9930d5738d113e0acf93c99ada35736e76;hb=HEAD) contains some implementations of extra transports. (ZeroMq for example)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check the code first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a legitimate question, and it can be extended to the more general question:

**How do I use other transport mechanisms with Apache Thrift?**

As Hcorg pointed out, because of ist modular structure of the framework, it is not quite hard to achieve that. Basically, one has to follow these steps (this is true for all languages supported by Thrift, not only C++)

- derive a specialized class from TTransport. In some cases this is an interface, not a base class, but that does not really matter.
- implement all the [methods needed](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h)
- for the server side, you may need a `TServerTransport` derivative

The existing implementations may serve as models, and despite the number of methods in `TTransport`, most of them are not really hard to implement.

Additionally, I also provided a specialized transport implementation to use STOMP with Delphi, based on a `TStreamTransport`. The relevant code can be found in the [`/contrib` Folder](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/contrib/Stomp/Thrift.Transport.STOMP.pas) and is worth a look. You know, one of the nice things about Thrift is that stuff work very similar in all languages.

Comment: Thank you! 

Actually, I want to implement a thrift client framework which handle connection management and other transport things. 

So I learned the procedure like this: 
1. derive a specialized class from TTransport, implement my logic in it, compile with thrift src to be a static lib 
2. No change happend to thrift IDL part, user just need know my specialized transport class name and use it to in his code. 
3. build his business code with my lib and thrift src/lib  that's all, right?

I find ZeroMQ example in thrift contrib is quite simple and clear, I'm reading it now

Comment: Essentially yes, that's it.